# Reading data from binary file correctly in Java

Tags: java, file, encryption, netbeans, binary

I have problem with reading understood data, when I used Parsing (char) the numbers became strange char in ASCII, here is the code :

```
static void doTestByteFiles() throws IOException {

   File file = new File("sample1.data");
   FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file); //Warning!!!!

   byte[] outByteArray = {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,(byte)'J',(byte)'a',(byte)'v',(byte)'a'};


   outStream.write(outByteArray);
   outStream.close();

   FileInputStream inStream = new  FileInputStream(file);

   int fileSize = (int) file.length();
   byte[] inByteArray = new byte[fileSize];
   inStream.read(inByteArray);

   for (int i = 0; i < fileSize; i++) {
     System.out.println((char) inByteArray[i]);
   }

inStream.close();
 }
```

the result:

(
2
<
F
P
J
a
v
a

result I expect :
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
J
a
v
a

I tried to use (byte) instead (char), same problem but the Java word became numbers in ASCII , Any help please ?

Comment: Your expectation is flawed. You should look up an ascii table.

Comment: You are mixing characters and bytes... So take a step back and describe what you want to do exactly.

Comment: Have you looked up those values in an actual ASCII table?

Comment: Guys I'm trying to use byteArray to store data in, and then reading from, the ASCII table says that 'a' letter for example equal 97 in Integer , so I tried to put 97 instead 'a' in the Array, but having another error. Thanks

Comment: This is what I said; you are mixing characters and bytes. Java does not use ASCII but Unicode

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in the byte[] array are interpreted as byte values. You have to write Intergers and convert them to byte inside the array.